# Как сделать закрытие формы fancybox при отправке запроса

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Как сделать закрытие формы fancybox при отправке запроса. Что-то не пойму как сделать. Буду рад любой помощи

```
document.getElementById('call-form2').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Предотвращаем отправку формы по умолчанию
  const formDataCall = new FormData(document.getElementById('call-form2'));
// Отправляем данные на сервер с помощью Fetch API
  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formDataCall 
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
    document.getElementById('call-form2').reset();
  
}
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Ошибка:", error);
    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чттобы закрыть форму fancybox при отправке запроса, нужно добавить вызов метода

```
fancybox.close()
```

в блок then. Этот метод закрывает текущий fancybox.

```
document.getElementById('call-form2').addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Предотвращаем отправку формы по умолчанию
  const formDataCall = new FormData(document.getElementById('call-form2'));
// Отправляем данные на сервер с помощью Fetch API
  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formDataCall 
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      document.getElementById('call-form2').reset();
      $.fancybox.close(); // Закрываем текущий fancybox
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Ошибка:", error);
    
  });
});
```

для  работы $.fancybox.close() нужно подключить  библиотеку jQuery. Если вы не используете jQuery, можно закрыть fancybox с помощью метода

```
window.parent.jQuery.fancybox.getInstance().close()
```